# URLs are UI in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, url-routing, friendly-id

Came across this [blog post](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/URLsAreUI.aspx) recently and wanted to Incorporate its ideas into my Rails project - URLs should be short, human readable, shareable, and shorten-able. Specifically, I want to learn how to make URLs shorten-able with Rails. The example he gives is https://stackoverflow.com/users/6380/scott-hanselman and https://stackoverflow.com/users/6380 are the same URLs, the text after the ID is ignored and `scott-hanselman` will be added after navigating to the page. This improves readability and share-ability.

I would like the `show` action in my resource URLs to auto-add the page's `<title>` after the ID when navigating to the page but ignore it when the user pastes it into the search bar. This allows for malleable titles.

Example below. All these URLs should bring you to the `resource` with an ID of '1'

`host/resource/1/exciting-blog-post`

`host/resource/1`

`host/resource/1/exciting-blog-post.html`

`host/resource/1/new-title-on-post`

**Edit:**

The biggest difficulty I am having is editing the URL after the user submits it, ie transforming `resource/1` to `resource/1/name_column`.

I have been able to redirect incorrect routes using the following in `config/routes.rb` - `get "/events/:id/*other", to: redirect('events/%{id}')`

Comment: Having a bunch of URLs with "duplicate" content is SEO poison...

Comment: https://github.com/norman/friendly_id

Comment: You don't need id's or even resource names in the url although keeping them is a good idea. Take a look at [FriendlyID](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) gem

Comment: Cool thanks for the friendly ID links. Looking it over it seems like it allows replacing numerical `ids` with text, is it possible to keep numerical with a text backup? @BradWerth do you have any links to further reading for that claim? I'd like to learn more.

Comment: FriendlyID just generates the slugs, the routing is entirely up to you.

Comment: maybe something like http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/creating-vanity-urls-in-rails? the trick is basically the to_param method...

Comment: I don't want most of the features of FriendlyId and am thus reluctant to include it and be forced to edit my DB tables and code. I have learned that adding `  get "/controller/:id/*other", to: redirect('controller/%{id}')` in `config/routes.rb` successfully redirects to the correct id, but I've been unable to redirect `controller/id` to `controller/id/DB_name_column`. Overriding `to_param` is not working. Any ideas?

Comment: By "to_param" is not working I mean that it is not working to re-route `controller/id` but `<%= link_to "event", controller_path(Controller.find(1)) %>`

Comment: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35652/what-is-duplicate-content-and-how-can-i-avoid-being-penalized-for-it-on-my-site
https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/103210/how-to-test-for-duplicate-content-penalties-from-google
https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/19032/can-duplicate-content-on-a-com-and-a-co-uk-site-impact-google-ranking
https://www.google.com/search?q=duplicate+content+site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fwebmasters.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this was really tricky to figure out, didn't even know I had access to a lot of these parameters before. FriendlyID is not required, and not even capable of solving this issue.

The resource I'm using below is "events".

First edit your `config/routes.rb` to accept `id/other_stuff`

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :events
  get "/events/:id/*other" => "events#show" #if any txt is trailing id, also send this route to events#show
end
```

Next modify `event_controller.show` to redirect if the URL is incorrect.

```
  def show
    #redirect if :name is not seen in the URL
    if request.format.html? 
      name_param = @event.name.parameterize
      url = request.original_url
      id_end_indx = url.index(@event.id.to_s) + (@event.id.to_s).length + 1 #+1 for '/' character
      ##all URL txt after id does not match name.parameterize
      if url[id_end_indx..-1] != @event.name.parameterize
        redirect_to "/events/#{@event.id}/#{name_param}"
      end
    end
  end
```

This will result in the exact same behavior as the Stack Overflow examples gave in the question.